# Burninate [superscript]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [superscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/superscript) tag doesn't seem to have much point; it literally covers <sup>superscript</sup> text, rather than some amazing new programming language ([I checked](http://esolangs.org/w/index.php?search=superscript)).

Can one really be a "superscript" expert? (Note the lack of a space between "super" and "script" before you answer!)

Comment: I think someone can be a super script expert, someone who knows more than regular experts. Oh darn it, I didn't just ignored your last sentence.. or did I? o.o

Comment: Apparently SuperScript is [some collection of shell utilities for UNIX](http://www.superscript.com/software.html).

Comment: @tepples SuperScript is a company that has made some scripts. Have a the tag [SuperScript] is as useful as having the tag [Microsoft] (oh god it has 2.9k questions).

Comment: Yes, that's possible.  Nothing very trivial about superscript text when the glyphs are not latin.  Or how to *easily* find their codepoints.  Or how to encode them if you have to use a language like C or C++.

Comment: We should be thankful that there isn't a `<mega>` or `<ultra>` tag in HTML. Otherwise we would end up with [tag:ultra] [tag:mega] [tag:superscript]. That being said, shouldn't this also lead to a discussion about [tag:subscript]?

Comment: @Zeta just put them both in the same bag.

Comment: @Hans Passant You raise good points. However, do we need a tag *specifically* for superscript/subscript questions? It could be argued that [tag:character-encoding] or [tag:unicode] would be "good enough" for that sort of thing.

Comment: It can just as easily be argued that an extra tag is good enough to allow SO users to quickly see if there's a point in spending time to read the question.  I'll never understand why users with burninate requests insist that questioners should use only a single [tag] on their questions.  Luckily they never do, the extra tag is quite harmless.

Comment: @HansPassant but, do we have questions in which that single tag would make sense without any other tags? I say with trepidation that the answer is "no".